# Some uitableviewcells not displaying all the data until I scroll the iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The data gets fetched from a web API and should populate the tableview.

Problem: Once data is fetched, the tableView populates most of the data but some data in the cells aren't showing up unless I scroll the tableView. Once scrolling back the tableView to that cell the data then starts to display.

Here's my code.

Properties:

```
var upcomingPrograms: [SabaCenterData.UpcomingProgram] = [] {
    didSet {
        self.stopActivityIndicator()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

var imageCache = [URL : UIImageView]()
```

View Cycle & Helper:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.fetchUpcomingPrograms()
}

func fetchUpcomingPrograms() {
    showActivityIndicator()
    GoogleDocsClient.shared().getUpcomingPrograms {
        (data, error) in
        if let data = data {
            self.upcomingPrograms = data
        } else {
            // FIXME: ERROR HANDLING!
        }
    }
}
```

Table View:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "upcomingProgramCell", for: indexPath) as! UpcomingProgramsCell
    let upcomingProgram = upcomingPrograms[indexPath.row]

    cell.upcomingProgramTextView.attributedText = makeAttributedString(title: upcomingProgram.title, subtitle: upcomingProgram.description)
    cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlaceHolder"))
    if let imageurl = URL(string: upcomingProgram.imageURL!) {
        if let img = imageCache[imageurl] {
            cell.accessoryView = img
        } else {
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageurl) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    let imgView = UIImageView(image: image)
                    imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 110.0)
                    imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
                    imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                    imageCache[imageurl] = imgView
                    performUIUpdatesOnMain {
                        cell.accessoryView = imgView
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

**Edit: The tableView is populated with data, but some data isn't displaying all of the data until I scroll up and down!**

Maybe because of these two functions?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

I'm dynamically adjusting the height of the cells based on the content. Also the cell has a textView (if that helps clarify the situation...).

**Edit 2: I uploaded the entire project here ->**  https://github.com/alimir1/Saba-Center

Comment: I suggest you use SDWebImage

Comment: Images download perfectly.... i have problem with the data

Comment: Ok.  You didn't clarify that.  Make sure you dispatch the `self.upcomingPrograms = data` on the main queue as the completion handler is probably not called on the main queue

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to call tableView.reloadData() somewhere.

As you scroll, it calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` automatically, because it deallocates cells to reuse them later. But it sounds like you don't have all of your data at once. Calling tableView.reloadData() will populate everything for you, but you haven't provided enough code to know where, specifically. Perhaps after `self.upcomingPrograms = data`?

Without further information, that's the best you're gonna get.

Comment: upcomingPrograms is a property observer that calls tableView.reloadData()

Comment: It isn't calling reloadData at the proper time, then. It sounds like it's calling it when you initially set data, and it doesn't have all the data to even fill a page yet. Then, you end up with more cells as you scroll, because scrolling triggers `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Figure out how to fire tableView.reloadData() from upcomingPrograms every time data is added, instead of just when it is iniitially added.

Comment: still not working. please see my update for question if it helps

Comment: so i found out the problem.... the images were stopping my text from displaying. i don't know why!

Comment: What type are you storing inside the imageCache dictionary? Is it an image view? How do you set up that view? If I were you, I would instead store the UIImage, and set up the UIImageView similarly to how you do if for a URL that does not exist in the imageCache yet, just to make sure it's being set up properly. Orrr, maybe it's setting it up like when it's not cached that is causing the problem. Maybe the view is just too big and is covering the text data?

Comment: The view isn't covering the data. i know because when i scroll down and scroll back up the SAME cell displays data properly. I removed uiimage from cellForIndex and the data seems to be displaying perfectly. I know it has to do with images...

Comment: `cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlaceHolder"))`  You never set the bounds of this image view or anything. Likely, your images haven't been fetched yet since that happens asynchronously, so on the first iteration you're using this `placeholder` image with whatever the default UIImageView frame is, again, perhaps covering your text data.  Then, when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called again, you have the image data, so it uses the properly formatted UIImageView with the not placeholder image.

Comment: The imageCache holds a dictionary of [URL : UIImageView]. I tried putting it as [URL : UIImage] instead but no fix... :( you can view entire project https://github.com/alimir1/Saba-Center

Comment: Test this by adding an else statement to the `if let imageurl` if statement that just prints a console statement saying you're using the placeholder image. I bet it'll trigger the first round, but won't be tirggering once you start scrolling.

Comment: Nope. The else statement isn't being executed.

Comment: Try similar tactic to figure out which if statement *is* getting executed and when. Breakpoints work well, but for this purpose since it's recursively triggered won't be as helpful as console logs in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts are about dequeue nature of cells and completion handler for async data fetching. Because cells are reusing by `.tableView`, you can handle wrong `cell` in your completion handler for data fetching.
You can try two ways.

First, try to retrieve correct cell right in the completion handler:

```
if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageurl) {
    if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        let imgView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 110.0)
        imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageCache[imageurl] = imgView
        performUIUpdatesOnMain {
            // Check it
            let initialCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            initialCell.accessoryView = imgView
        }
    }
}
```

Second, try to mark you current `cell` as `weak` & copy it:

```
/// Check it
__weak let weakCell = cell
if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageurl) {
    if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        let imgView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 110.0)
        imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageCache[imageurl] = imgView
        performUIUpdatesOnMain {
            // Check it
            weakCell.accessoryView = imgView
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I recommend you to override `prepareForReuse()` ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse)) for your custom cell and nullify `.accessoryView` to avoid misleading usage of wrong images for dequeued cells. Something like this:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    accessoryView = nil
}
```

Comment: what's really annoying me is that the cells "underneeth" the views are perfectly loaded...

Comment: Huh. In this case, it can be anything. All I can advise you in this situation is to check your view hierarchy to be sure that you don't have problems with your view configuration. [Debug View Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html) is very useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Alright... I got the answer!!

So the problem was the images. I simply used [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke) and added the following code in custom tableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class UpcomingProgramsCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var upcomingProgramTextView: UITextView!

    var sabaProgramsImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        sabaProgramsImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 110.0)
        sabaProgramsImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        accessoryView = sabaProgramsImageView
    }
}
```

And in my UpComingProgramsVC:

```
    if let imageurl = URL(string: upcomingProgram.imageURL!) {
        Nuke.loadImage(with: imageurl, into: cell.sabaProgramsImageView)
    }
```